# Rails: difference between self.function and self.class.function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, self

I am not sure I understand why I get a NoMethodError exception if I replace "var3 = self.class.function2" with "var3 = self.function2"

When should I use self and when should I use self.class ?

```
class TestClass
  var1 = nil

  def self.function1
    var1 = "hello"
  end

  def self.function2
    p self.function1
    var2 = "world"
  end

  def function3
    var3 = self.class.function2
    p var3
  end
end


myvar = TestClass.new
myvar.function3
```

Comment: `def self.` are class methods. `def function3` is a instance method. to call the class methods you could do your `self.class.function2`, but normally you would just do `TestClass.function2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def self.function2` is your class method that can not be called with instance of class. It call like `TestClass.function2`. While `def function3` is instance method. You are calling it right.

```
myvar = TestClass.new
myvar.function3
```

So if we follow flow. Under `function3` self will become instance that is calling that function.

```
var3 = self.class.function2 # Here self is myvar
# self.class == TestClass
# self.class.function2 == TestClass.function2 # No error
# self.function2 == myvar.function2 # error, Calling class method with instance of class.
```

Now if you try to call class method with instance it will surely through error.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `def self.function2` means, the `function2` is "wired" to the class (`TestClass`) not to the instance of class (`TestClass.new` return instance of class `TestClass`). The call `self.class` returns the class (`TestClass`) where is the `function2` based.

The `function2` can be also called this way: `TestClass.function2`